# Can't add user to a group using MailChimp API 3.0

Tags: php, list, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I'm trying to update my code for subscribing new users to my MailChimp newsletter.

I would like it to add the user to a group, so that I can distinguish between users when sending out newsletters. This code, however, subscribes the user but does not add it to any group. What am I doing wrong? I am using the MailChimp API 3.0.

My code:

```
$apiKey     = 'XXXX';
$list_id    = 'XXXX';
$memberId   = md5(strtolower($data['email']));
$dataCenter = substr($apiKey,strpos($apiKey,'-')+1);

$url = 'https://' . $dataCenter . '.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/' . $list_id . '/members/' . $memberId;

$json = json_encode(array(
    'email_address' => $data['email'],
    'status'        => $data['status'], // "subscribed","unsubscribed","cleaned","pending"
    'merge_fields'  => array(
        'FNAME'         => $data['firstname'],
        'LNAME'         => $data['lastname'],
        'GROUPINGS'     => array(
            0 => array(
                'name'   => 'Interests',
                'groups' => array( $data['tag'] ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
));

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'user:' . $apiKey);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);

$result   = curl_exec($ch);
$httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are passing Interest grouping in the wrong array.
you need to pass the interest group id in `interests` array with value as `true`.

```
$json = json_encode(array(
    'email_address' => 'test@example.com',
    'status'        => 'subscribed', 
    'merge_fields'  => array(
        'FNAME'         => 'FirstName',
        'LNAME'         => 'LastName',
     ),
    'interests'     => array( 
        '9143cf3bd1' => true,
        '789cf3bds1' => true
     ),
));
```

You will get the id of interest groups [`9143cf3bd1,789cf3bds1` in above example] of the list by requesting to this URL

```
/lists/{list_id}/interest-categories
```

[see doc here](http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/lists/interest-categories)

If you want to remove the subscriber from the group, you need to set its value to `false` in your update request.

Comment: Hi Mûhámmàd,

My code is:

array(
 'email_address' => 'test@example.com',
 'status'        => 'pending',
 'merge_fields'  => array(
  'FNAME'         => 'FirstName',
  'LNAME'         => 'LastName',
    ),
    'interests' => array(
        '8c4bb7fbfd' => true
    ),
)

But it still doesn't add the user to the interest group. It gives me a 200 header though.

Comment: Glad to know that @TobiasChristianJensen :)

Comment: I'm trying the same thing but I'm getting *400 Bad request* error. and message is: Invalid interest ID: '8f14b8ad10'.

Comment: Am I adding the ID wrong... I got the `"list_id": "8f14b8ad10",` from this GET request: /lists/{list_id}/interest-categories

Comment: Tried recently, looks like `interests` array should not have direct keys, but arrays instead: `'interests'     => array( 
       array( '9143cf3bd1' => true),
       array('789cf3bds1' => true)
     ),`

Comment: @Kos You are wrong. Just tested it. The answer has the correct format.